# iCloud Advanced Data Protection asking to remove device with iOS 16.3

Tags: ios, icloud

To enable Advanced Data Protection, iCloud wants me to remove my iPhone which it says can't be updated to the latest version of iOS.

I have an iPhone X with iOS 16.3. I am confused because Apple's official website states that the encryption is available starting iOS 16.2.

Why then is it not letting me enable it on my account and forcing me to remove my iPhone?

Comment: Have you tried setting it up from that iPhone?

Comment: @Ezekiel yes, and it shows the same message as on my Mac: that I need to remove the iPhone from my Apple ID in order to continue...

Comment: Then it sounds like it's referring to a different iPhone. Is that possible? The iPhone that needs to be removed shouldn't refer to itself in the 3rd person.

Comment: @Ezekiel I hear you, I'm surprised too. This is the only iPhone left on my account. I made sure to remove the old ones. I suspect maybe it is because I updated my Mac to the latest version of OS X. And perhaps that last version of OS X requires iOS 17 to exchange the encryption keys...

Comment: I would give Apple a call, they may be able to tell more clearly what's going on

Comment: @Ezekiel Thank you! I fixed it! I went to try one last time on my Mac, went in Apple ID settings, and noticed a strange situation: even though I had successfully removed all old iPhones from Find My, an iPhone was left in my list of devices. I had made the assumption reading tutorials online that all my devices should show in Find My. Turns out some devices can be in the "Apple ID > Devices" list but not show on Find My. So... my bad. Thanks for helping me with that.

Comment: @user3491456 That looks like an answer - please create an answer from that information.

Comment: Thank you for asking / answering and ticking the answered - these sorts of questions can be super useful as others find the same undocumented / un-obvious place to influence the "roster" of devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! I went to try one last time on my Mac, went in Apple ID settings, and noticed a strange situation: even though I had successfully removed all old iPhones from Find My, an iPhone was left in my list of devices. I had made the assumption reading tutorials online that all my devices should show in Find My. Turns out some devices can be in the "Apple ID > Devices" list but not show on Find My.